# "Раскрасневшихся на морозе молодцОв" — ошибка?

Tags: грамотная-речь, орфоэпия, окончания

"Зулейха открывает глаза" Гузель Яхиной:

> Игнатов едет в голове каравана. Временами останавливается и пропускает отряд вперёд, пристально оглядывая каждого — и угрюмых кулаков в санях, и своих раскрасневшихся на морозе ***молодцов***.

Это ошибка и должно быть "молодцев" или всё-таки "молоде́ц" иногда употребляют в значении "мо́лодец"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я думаю, что все правильно — именно ***молодцо́в.***

В словаре Ожегова:
I. МО́ЛОДЕЦ, -дца, муж. В народной словесности: удалец, храбрец. *Добрый мо́лодец.*
II. [**МОЛОДЕ́Ц**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ogegova/109174), -дца, муж.
1. Молодой человек, сильный, крепкого сложения. *Бравый молоде́ц.*
3. *обычно мн.* Человек, обычно сильный, смелый, бесшабашный (разг.).
*Разбойные молодцы́. Ловкачи-молодцы́.*

В словаре А. А. Зализняка: [молодцы́](https://glosum.ru/%D0%97%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%86), молодцо́в, молодца́м, молодцо́в, молодца́ми, молодца́х.

*Бери половину молодцов по своему выбору, будешь поддерживать огнем* (Ю. Никитин); *А когда посыльные вернулись, был устроен пир, щедрые брызги от которого попали в кружки караульничих и дозорных молодцов* (Е. Сухов); *Рауль напряженно следил за ходом дела и вселял бодрость и энергию в души своих бравых молодцов матросов* (Д. Ф. Купер).

Comment: Спасибо, Римма!